# Python - print without brackets and quotes

Tags: python

In python when i run this code

```
calories = 565
print('\'calories\':', calories )
```

returns

```
("'calories':", 565)
```

but i want to print without the parenthesis and quotes, how can i do this

Comment: Sounds like you're using Python 2. In Python 2 you can just write `print "'calories':", calories` without any parentheses.

Comment: Or better, switch to python3 right now :-)

Comment: You are probably using python 2. Either switch to python 3 or write `from __future__ import print_function`. This will allow you to use the python 3 print function in python 2